# Find a particular warning in log and kill PID with batch script

Tags: batch-file, pid, findstr

We have an "Intermittent database disconnection" issue (can be find this message in Application log) and currently I am finding PID manually and killing (but not restarting Application to avoid downtime).
/i need help to search the disconnect string on all logs (log itself contains PID name) and kill pid currently processing.

I have created one script but it can delete the file (if it is not locked) but I'm looking for complete solution, so the same can be scheduled on windows scheduler.
Below is script currently I have created (not much helpful but I can delete logs after killing PID manually)

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "MySearchString= Failed to connect to <Database server>"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d ^| findstr /s /M /c:"%MySearchString%" C:\ABCDE\temp\faulykernel\*.*') do del "%%~i"  >> C:\ABCDE\temp\script\output\faultykernel.txt
```

Comment: You are piping the dir results to findstr and also use a recursive search with a file reference, in this case the piped input is ignored and so is useless.  You are redirecting the output of the del, but there is no output on standard output stream, just error output would get text but to catch this you have to use `2>> filename` Otherwise you don't supply any details on the fouindstring but delete every file containing the MySearchString.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, 
Actually I wanted to get the pid and kill pid too (having database disconnection error) along with log files...

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr /smc:"%MySearchString%" *') do @ECHO del "%a"`

Comment: findstr /s /M /c:" <String needs to find>" C:\ABCD\temp\faulykernel\*.* > C:\ABCD\temp\script\output\TEST.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=_,." %%a in ("C:\ABCD\temp\script\output\TEST.txt") do (
 
 TSKILL %%b
)

Comment: thank you all for help, I have written complete required code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

findstr /s /M /c:" " C:\ABCD\temp\faulykernel*.* > C:\ABCD\temp\script\output\TEST.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=_,." %%a in ("C:\ABCD\temp\script\output\TEST.txt") do (

```
TSKILL %%b
```

)
echo %sc%